# Ansible parses my YML comment and mistake it with k=v

Tags: ansible

In this code block running ansible 2.9.6:

// System/group_vars/all/vars.yml

```
---

# AWS S3
# User Ansible
# Permissions put/get on arn:aws:s3:::snap/backup-db/*
# Plus d'infos: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=eu-west-2#/users/ansible?section=permissions
s3_access_key: {{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/iam/ansible/access-key', region='eu-west-2', aws_access_key=aws_access_key, aws_secret_key=aws_secret_key) }}
```

Gives the following error:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unacceptable key (unhashable type: 'AnsibleMapping')

The error appears to be in 'System/group_vars/all/vars.yml': line 32, column 63, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

# Plus d'infos: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=eu-west-2
                                                              ^ here

There appears to be both 'k=v' shorthand syntax and YAML in this task. Only one syntax may be used.
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

It thinks that `region=eu-west-2` is a key value that is mixed with YML syntax.

What can I do to avoid Ansible throwing this wrongful error since it's in a YML comment ?

Thank you :)

Comment: You would need to show us your entire `vars.yml` file (or at least everything leading up to line 32).

Comment: I don't see how it's relevant since shortening the URL to remove any sign of the `=` sign in the YML comment "fixes" the issue. But i've edited my question to reflect some part of what's before. It's like just a regular vars.yml file honestly

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem you've described using your sample data. I don't think we're going to be able to help out here unless you can provide a sample configuration in your question that reproduces the error.

Comment: Thank you for trying to reproduce it. In fact, the error was just after the line that I removed for my example: I've update my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake caused by a line **right after this one**:

```
# Plus d'infos: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=eu-west-2#/users/ansible?section=permissions
s3_access_key: {{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/iam/ansible/access-key', region='eu-west-2', aws_access_key=aws_access_key, aws_secret_key=aws_secret_key) }}
```

Should be:

```
# Plus d'infos: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=eu-west-2#/users/ansible?section=permissions
s3_access_key: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/iam/ansible/access-key', region='eu-west-2', aws_access_key=aws_access_key, aws_secret_key=aws_secret_key) }}"
```

note the quotes around the `"{{ lookup }}"`. The error message was trying to tell me so at the very last part of the error ("might be an issue with
missing quotes") I just was focused on why my comment was parsed and interpreted as `key=value`